# Add a scroll bar to text area

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I use Eclipse Window Builder. When I click the button, something will be written on the screen. But since my prints are long, I want to use a scroll pane.

```
public class uyg2 extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                uyg2 frame = new uyg2();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public uyg2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(32, 29, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBounds(10, 63, 233, 173);
    contentPane.add(textArea);

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(249, 10, 173, 118);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
}
```

Comment: 1) Add the text area directly to the scroll pane & **only** the scroll pane. Add the scroll pane to the container. But that alone won't solve the problem here.. 2) **Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead *use layout managers*, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).**

Comment: 1. Stop using `null` layouts, this is going to work against you; 2. Use a `JScrollPane` instead of a `ScrollPane`; 3. Wrap the `JScrollPane` around the `JTextArea` as demonstrated in [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Comment: *"I've tried a method.."* Please don't use the answer area for updates to the question. Instead [edit] the question. Further tips: 1) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: 3) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on...

```
public class uyg1 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    uyg1 frame = new uyg1();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public uyg1() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Test");
        textArea.setSize(400, 400);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

`textArea.setSize(400, 400);` is irrelevant as the layout manager will deal with it.  You can provide sizing hints via the `JTextArea(String, int, int)` constructer, but remember, this is the number of characters in width/height, not pixels.

The following are giving you issues...

```
frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

because `frame` is undefined.  Since the class extends from `JFrame`, they are pointless, it should just be

```
getContentPane().add(scroll);
setVisible(true);
```

but, I'd add...

```
pack();
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

before it, as it will give you a generally better experience

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the TextArea to the ScrollPane. Don't add the textarea tho the contentpane.